# Trouble upgrading from Rails 6.0.0.rc2 to 6.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to upgrade from Rails 6.0.0.rc2 to 6.0.0.

When I run `bundle update rails`, I get:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.10) was resolved to 0.10.10, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.1, < 6.1)
```

In my `Gemfile` for `active_model_serializers` I have:

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.10', require: true, github: 'rails-api/active_model_serializers', branch: 'rails-6-0-rc2'
```

Why am I getting this error and what can I do about it?

Comment: What does the line for rails look like in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: If that is the only bundler error you get, you might suffer from https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6620... Check out the pointers there, especially manually walking through `Gemfile.lock` and watching for possible conflicting versions. And perhaps open an issue at bundler, as this should not happen I guess... 

By the way, we successfully run active model serializers using the `0-10-stable` branch under Rails 6.